# Stochastic discount factor derivation

Tags: finance, asset-pricing

What are the intermediate steps to arrive at equation (4) in Lettau and Wachter 2007? Here is the paper: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Bc0oOqKGm0otYbywf5gdfwzpRpA-D11p/view

I am confused why there is a term $x_t\epsilon_{d,t+1}$. Is this coming from solving a ode?